# How do i plot a graph in ggplot 2 using values from a dataframe and converting them to rounded percent label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have these values

```
PCT_Asian | PCT_Black | PCT_Hispanic | PCT_White | PCT_Other
.26554     .25454     .145454         .22454      .23123
```

I would like to see a bar plot where the x axis labels under each bin

```
PCT_Asian to Asian
PCT_Black to Black
Pct_White to White and so on.....
```

Also converts the values to proper percent labels

27%, 25%, 15%, 22%, and 23%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- str_split("PCT_Asian | PCT_Black | PCT_Hispanic | PCT_White | PCT_Other", "[|]", simplify = T) %>% str_trim(.)
b <- str_split(".26554     .25454     .145454         .22454      .23123", " ", simplify = T) %>% as.numeric(.) %>% na.omit(.)
tibble(a, b) %>% 
  mutate(x = str_remove(a, "PCT_")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, b)) + 
   geom_col() + 
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: i can't work straight from the data frame? I see you created an a and b. I have these values already imported from an excel file. Do i have to recreate it again?

Comment: No. Just use your data.frame. But change the names `"a"` and `"b"` according the names in you dataframe. Since you provided not your actual data.frame in your question, I had to creat it by own.

Comment: I'm confused though because the data frame is one row with the PCT headers. here it looks like you split them and made them into separate lines.

Comment: try `df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols =everything())`. The keyword is "make the data from wide to long", since ggplot needs data in the long format.